# Removing an object from a list in MongoDb with its index using pyMongo and MongoEngine?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

i have a document in my MongoDB database which contains as list of reference fields:

```
class US(Document):
    name = StringField(required=True, max_length=200)
    timestamp = StringField(required=True, max_length=50)
    list = ListField(ReferenceField(Stk))
```

Now, I want to remove a certain index (i=15) from that list. I tried something like

```
US.objects(id=us.id).update(pull__list = )
```

but i cannot get it to work. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB doesn't support removing a specific list element in a single operation (unless it's the first or last element - using `$pop`).

But python's `pop` does allow this, so you can do something like:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']

db.mycollection.insert_one({'array': [x for x in range(20)]})

document = db.mycollection.find_one()
array = document['array']
array.pop(15)  # Remove element at index 15

db.mycollection.update_one({'_id': document['_id']}, {'$set': {'array': array}})

print(db.mycollection.find_one())
```

gives:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5fde48b597315f732fb0a1d1'), 'array': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19]}
```